# What word means "the thing you added"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What word means "the thing(s) you added to something"? It's something like 'addium' or something Latin-like! But I can't really remember.

I remember seeing it used in some context as follows.

1. You write a comment.
2. Then you want to add something to it, you'd write:

> Old comment.
>   
>   
>   [the word goes here]
>   
>   
>   New comment.
>   
>   And it's not *edit* or *P.S.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Addendum*, plural *addenda*.

Latin gerundive meaning "what is/was to be added", plural "things that are/were to be added".

Comment: Yes, that's the word I was talking about! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you referring to the word *addendum*.

Answer (score 1):

Another word you could use is *codicil*.

Comment: The *only* definition for *codicil* given in both Chambers (http://www.chambersharrap.co.uk/) and ODO (http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/codicil?q=codicil (British) *and* http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/codicil (American)) is in relation to *a supplement to a will*.

Comment: @TrevorD:  You got me.  Here I am, confronted by the big guns and all I have is a peashooter.  Oh well, here goes anyway:  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/codicil?db=dictionary, where a codicil is defined in part as "any supplement; appendix."  The same "authority" also defines an addendum as a thing to be added, an appendix, a supplement.  I feel so ashamed!

Comment: @rhetorician: I believe it doesn't have to be a supplement to a will, but it has to be a supplement to a legal document, so it has to be a little sub-document in itself: not a single item in a list, which can be an addendum.

Comment: @Cerberus:  Except when "codicil" is used in an almost metaphorical--but surely analogical--fashion, as in polymath Kenneth Burke's "Definition of Man," which ends with ". . . and rotten with perfection," which he refers to (probably with his tongue planted firmly in his cheek) as his "wry codicil."  His definition, by the way, is a pretty good one.  It's not perfect, but then what is?

Comment: @rhetorician: And he calls those last words, *and rotten with perfection*, a "codicil"? That would indeed have to be metaphorical...

Comment: @Cerberus: And what, pray tell, is not at least somewhat metaphorical? Example: A person who says "I see," when what he really means is he understands. No, that won't do, because if he understands, what is he standing under? Now I'm really confused. Don